# pycharm module directory import error problem

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm

I am using pycharm and use 2 windows10 64bit PCs (one is a laptop and the other is desktop) for studying python3.

Recently, I found module importing issues which is different between PC.
Both pycahrm version is same: PyCharm 2022.2.2 (Community Edition).
Python version is also same: 3.9.
But when I import modules from main.py, I found the below difference.

[directory]
After the below directory,
C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\python_programming_demo_app-0.0.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XP9E.png)

The main.py is in dir1. In the main.py, to import module A, I can write the below.

1, from dir1.dir2 import A

2, from dir2 import A

PC 1(laptop): The above 1 and 2 both work. But when you create main.exe by pyinstaller, only 1 can work well. (main.exe created with 2 said no module named dir2 after executing main.exe.)

PC 2(desktop): The above 2 only works and main.exe created by pyinstaller also works. But the one never works on pycharm with the error message of [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir1']

Does anyone encounter the similar situation??
Is this caused by setting of pycharm??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is why one PC can work with both 1 and 2. But the other PC only work with 2. I want to know if there is any setting problem or not.
1, from dir1.dir2 import A 
2, from dir2 import A